# Code to update the dropdown list from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

Find in answer the code to update the dropdown list from database. Kinldy let know if there is a better alternate method for the same.

Comment: This is not a question. It has been shared so that someone can find this useful and also to know if there is a better method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                         DataSource = '<%# Status %>'
                         DataTextField  = "status">
                         </asp:DropDownList>

protected DataTable Status
    {
        get
        {
             DataTable dt  = new DataTable();

            using (con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string fetch_qry = @"select status from table";

                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(fetch_qry, con))
                {

                    adpt.Fill(dt);                    

                }
            }

                return dt;
        }
    }
```

Important note: This will only work if the DataBind function is called as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
```

`this.DataBind();` will also work, but it will bind all the controls in the page. It’s better to be specific.

Alternately the DataSource and DataTextField can be declared at the code page instead of the design page as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList1.DataSource = Status;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "status";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
```

In case if the drop down list is present inside the Grid View; DataBind function at the gridview level would bind the data in drop down list present in data grid: `GridView1.DataBind();`